# Find a Four-element Abelian Subgroup of $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Prof. Charles Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra" provides this exercise:

> Ch 7 (Groups of Permutations) 
>   Part B #3 - Find a four-element abelian sub-group of $S_5$. Write its table.

Please provide guidance on how to answer this question.

I'm guessing that I need to come up with a permutation table:

$$\begin{matrix}
1& 2& 3& 4& 5&\\
?& ?& ?& ?& ?&\\ 
\end{matrix}
$$

Then, I need to compose $f$ (where f defines the initial table) 5x in order to get $S_5$. However, I'm unsure if that's correct, and how I'd proceed once I found $S_5$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "compose $f$ 5x in order to get $S_5$", but if it means $f$ will generate $S_5$, that would be incorrect (because then $S_5$ would be cyclic.

Comment: What abelian groups do you know which have order $4$? Can you find copies of them within $S_5$?

Comment: Take the cyclic subgroup generated by $(1234)(5)$, as given by AmWhy already (above link).

Answer (score 2):

Not that in any group of permutations non-overlapping cycles commute with each other. So, if you find two non-overlapping cycles of order $2$, then the subgroup generated by them will be a four-element abelian subgroup. Any cycle of order $2$ is simply a transposition. So, for example, a subgroup generated by transpositions $(1 2)$ and $(3 4)$ is an example of a desired subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since an element always commutes with itself, the cyclic group generated by a four cycle would be an Abelian Group of order 4:

<(1234)> = {(1234), (13)(24), (1432), id}, isomorphic to Z mod 4

The previous answer, {id, (12), (34), (12)(34)} is isomorphic to Klien-4

Since these are the only Abelian Groups of order 4, and the only groups as well, all Abelian subgroups of S5 will be of the form:

1. <(abcd)> = {id, (abcd), (ac)(bd), (adcb)}
2. {id, (ab), (cd), (abcd)}

where a,b,c,d are distinct integers between 1 and 5